# Popping up new dialog box without redirecting to another page like IMDb log in

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written a web application which extracts data from a DB and displays it in the form of a table. Now when people want to edit these values, they are redirected to a different page. I have received a CR, for implementing everything in a single page w/o redirecting the users to any other page.

My question is if I want to give them the editing option in a new window (like when we click on IMDb's log in link, a new dialog box pops up in the same window blurring the background), how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery impromptu ( http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/ ) for simple modal boxes, which can be styled and used for various things like a table with editable boxes for the row to be edited.

Otherwise you can also use jquery editable ( demo: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html )